# Use all system memory in Solaris

Tags: perl, shell, memory, solaris

I am doing server testing and intentionally trying to crash a Solaris server by using all memory.  Server has a ulimit of 15 GB (several hundred GB of total system/swap memory).  Is there a straight forward way of doing this using a shell/Perl script? (*Edit*: This is in a hardened/secured environment so the only tool I have access to is Perl [and shell of course]).

Background: What is actually being tested is failover of essential processes to another server.  Lately we have been having a number of processes "go out of control" and consume all system resources thus causing server to crash (separate issue).  I am trying to create a simple repeatable scenario to test the response to this situation.

Comment: asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ might also yield more answers

Comment: Thanks.  Asked over at [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58130/use-all-system-memory-in-solaris)

Comment: You could use a fork bomb. `perl -e 'fork while 1'`

Comment: @squiguy - that will hit the per-user process limit (IIRC, around 30k processes) long before it hits any memory limit.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming /tmp is mounted on tmpfs and you didn't set a quota on it, (i.e. the default configuration), here is a way to use almost all of your memory using a shell script (beware that your system will be barely usable as soon as your RAM is exhausted):

```
#!/bin/ksh

function trapped
{
  echo "Eatswap done"
  rm -f /tmp/eatSwap.*
  exit
}

function showFreeSpace
{
  freeSpace=$(swap -s | sed -e 's/.*, //' -e 's/k.*//')
  echo free space = $freeSpace KB
}

trap trapped 2
counter=0
i=0
showFreeSpace
fs=$freeSpace
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/eatSwap.$i bs=$(($fs/10)) count=1024 2>/dev/null || trapped
  sleep 2
  showFreeSpace
  i=$((i+1))
done
echo "done"
sleep 2
rm -f /tmp/eatSwap.*
```

Comment: /tmp is mounted on tmpfs.  Is it true that filling up tmpfs will fill up both swap and physical memory?  I thought it was just swap.

Comment: It can't be just swap. That would make tmpfs useless. When you write to tmpfs, you write to RAM. If there is not enough RAM available, data previously written in /tmp is paginated out to the swap area as long as there is free swap available.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can allocate a fixed amount of memory quite precisely through strings, and the repetition operator `x`. As Perl stores characters in a two-byte representation, the following function will return a scalar that points to `$x` MB of memory:

```
sub allocate_MB {
   my ($x) = @_;
   "0" x ( $x / 2 * 2**(20))
}
```

(however, only tested on Ubuntu with perl 5.12)

When Perl can't allocate any more memory, it will die with a [message telling you so](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Out-of-memory!).

A simple `my @stor; push @stor, allocate_MB(200) while 1` should quickly hit any limit.

Comment: Perl is quite slow to allocate memory. Another issue is perl is 32 bit on Solaris so you would need to launch a bunch of these scripts to consume several hundreds of gigabytes.